# FullCalendar v2 beta columnFormat not rendering properly

Tags: fullcalendar

In `v1` I could render change the `columnFormat` to something like

```
'dddd MMMM d'
```

which would output for example:

```
Sunday January 25, Monday January 26, Tuesday January 27
```

I wanted to upgrade to the `v2 beta` and now the same format renders this:

```
Sunday January 0, Monday January 1, Tuesday January 2
```

This occurs on any month or week view. It always renders `d` starting at 0. [The docs](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs2/text/columnFormat/) haven't changed. `d` is a valid `moment.js` formatting character so I'm really not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In moment.js d is the day of the week. D is the day of the month.
Use D instead of d.